# MongoDB how to not return document after findOneAndUpdate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am searching for many different ways that could help to save bandwidth and data. In my node-js backend. I found out the data return from MongoDB after update operation is not used at all. So I decided to save my users some bandwidth by not returning any by calling e.g. 
`res.status(200).json();`

But some thoughts cross my mind, MongoDB is actually passing data/document back after update operation. Thus, even though I choose not to return any data to my user. There will still be data sending back to my node-js backend. In other word, that might add up some extra unnecessary cost to my hosting of the database.

How to let findOneAndUpdate or any update operation do not return data. Or do you have any tricks and tips on saving cost? :)

**Example of one of my findOneAndUpdate code**

```
feedbacks.findOneAndUpdate({
    '_id': feedbackId
}, {
    'status': status
}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(chalk.red(err));
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    console.log(chalk.green('UPDATE: (Super Admin) Feedback status'));
    res.status(200).json();
});
```

Comment: Use `updateOne` then. It only returns the matched details.

Comment: You could add a project to your statement to only return the `_id` field (after the `filter` and `update` section) like described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet, thanks for the suggestion, I just checked `updateOne`, it looks like a good way to limit/reduce  return data. `{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }`

Comment: @Florian Schlag, thank you too. I read the link you provided. If I am not wrong, by using ur approach. I could limit every update using `projection` and return only `{ "_id" : "xxxxx" }`. I will do a bytesize comparison tmr to see which one save more. (To make sure) thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Updates, not so sure if limiting the return fields will save cost, but I will go for the least size one. Thanks a lot for the great answers. I will list the compared result here for others as notes. Credits to @Anthony Winzlet and @Florian Schlag  Thank you for your time :)

**1. Method: `updateOne`**

Return fields:

```
{"n":1,"nModified":1,"opTime":{"ts":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","t":14},"electionId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","ok":1,"operationTime":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","$clusterTime":{"clusterTime":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","signature":{"hash":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","keyId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}}
```

> byteSize: 286

**2. Method: add `projection` in `findOneAndUpdate` and only return the `_id`**

Return fields:

```
{"_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

> byteSize: 34